# Calling instance members in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, declaration

I'm trying to use a `variable` with a `block` as `type` from an instance. I have tried all the code in the `viewController` I'm in and everything works. Now, I've moved parts of the code to a `viewModel` and call the `method` and the `block`. But for some reason the `method` isn't even triggered. Looks like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) ExperienceListFetchData *fetchData;

[_fetchData updateViewForCurrentTrip];

_fetchData.completion = ^void(void){
    NSLog(@"YAY");
};
```

So, first, I call the method from the class, and then the `completion` `block`.

I think it has to do with how I declare things in the `viewModel`:

In the `.h` file under `interface`:

```
- (void) updateViewForCurrentTrip;
@property void (^completion)(void);
```

Like I mentioned, the code I'm calling works great if I keep it in my `view` class, so I don't think I need to show you any actual code. According to the debugger, `[_fetchData updateViewForCurrentTrip];` isn't even activated.

Comment: Where do you assign an instance to the `fetchData` property? Where do you call the block? The code you have shown is assigning a block to the property (which, if `fetchData` is `nil` won't do anything). Also, you shouldn't bypass the getter and access the backing Ivar unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Oh my, oh my, I had completely forgotten to initialize `fetchData`: `_fetchData = [[ExperienceListFetchData alloc] init];` Thanks!